# How to set china tianditu map with react-native-maps in react-native in ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I'm using `React-Native-Maps` with `ReactNative`  to develop IOS app . It contains some maps , I want to use china tianditu as the basemap. I found that there is a `UrlTile` api in `React-Native-Maps`, I try to give it a `urlTemplate` ,but it seems doesn't work .
Here is the code :

  `<UrlTile  urlTemplate='http://t{subDomain}.tianditu.com/DataServer?T=vec_c&x={col}&y={row}&l={level}' maximumZ={19} />`

Comment: Are you able to update your question to add more information about how it does not work? Is there an error message?

Comment: Actually, I'm new to `ReactNative`, I want to add `tianditu` map with `UrlTile` . But with this url template `http://t{subDomain}.tianditu.com/DataServer?T=vec_c&x={col}&y={row}&l={level}' `, It doesn't work . Is there any right `UrlTemplate` to load it?

Answer (score -1):

```
<MapView
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
  />
```

You have to set latitude & longitude of "tianditu". It will focus on your initial region and show when you open map.